# Share object instance between scenes in an mac os x cocoa storyboard

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

In an appkit storyboard targeting mac os x 10.10+.

Is there a way to have InterfaceBuilder instantiate a custom model object and then have InterfaceBuilder inject the instance in to multiple view controllers as IBOutlets?

I can only get it to work in a single scene (controller).

Basically I want to use InterfaceBuilder as a graphical IOC Container.